# Changing calender view with month scope sp2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, view, sharepoint-calendar, farm-solution, scope

[image]

I want to change the calender view to a week view. I know the default way through the webpart setting. But the week view scope is to big. Is it possible to get just one part of the month view like in the snippet?